# Java: объявление константы без значения

Tags: android, java

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой, что нельзя объявить кностанту без значения.

```
private final int CODE_ONE;
```

Компилятор ругается и требует дать константе значение. Но я это сделать не могу, т.к. значение нужно задать позже, которые мне нужно, и которые уже менять будет нельзя.

```
CODE_ONE = trest + var1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На то она и константа, что ее значение нельзя менять. Но можно создать под это дело свой класс, у которого будут методы set\get. метод set проверяет специальный флаг "установки значения" и не допускает повторной инициализации.

Набросок кода. (возможно есть опечатки)

```
class Constanta {
  int data;
  bool was_set;
  Constanta() {
    data = 0;
    was_set = false;
  }

  const int get() {
    if (!was_set) {
       throw new Exception("Not initalize!");
    }
    return data;
  }

  void set(int value) {
    if (was_set) {
       throw new Exception("Not able to initialized twice");
    }
    data = value;
    was_set = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

В такой декларации разрешается инициализация final или сразу или в конструкторе:

```
public class MyClass {
   private final int code;

   public MyClass(){
     code=10;
   }

   public MyClass(int trest, int var1) {
     code=trest+var1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Константные значения можно задавать в конструкторе, после необходимой вам инициализации.